# Java Swing dynamic JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have populated a combobox *B1* from database. When itemStateChanged event raises it should populate another combobox *B2*, but its not working.

```
ArrayList1 = //call method in database connection class()
for (int j = 0; j < ArrayList1.size(); j++) 
{
    if (j == 0)
    {
        combobox1.addItem("Select Any");
    }
    combobox1.addItem(ArrayList1.get(j));
}


combobox1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) 
    {
        String catName = (String)combobox1.getSelectedItem();
        if (!catName.equalsIgnoreCase("Select Any"))
        {
            ArrayList2=//call method in DB class with cat_name as argument
            for(int i=0;i < ArrayList2.size();i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    combobox2.addItem("Select Any");
                }
                combobox2.addItem(ArrayList2.get(i));                   
            }                   
        }
    }           
});
```

first combobox gets populated from database, but after selecting any item from it second combobox keeps empty.

and why debugging this my computer hangs on?

Comment: Question: did you check that Array_list2 is not empty after call to DB? Adding a trace here would make sure the problem is not in the code you don't show in your example (the DB method).

Comment: but when i m going to debug it then it'll hang ma computer??then how can i debug it?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: I agreed to ur point but i have made it randomly.I'll keep diz in mind..

Comment: @Geetanjali you don't need to perform debugging from your IDE, a simple trace with `System.out.println(...)` would be enough, we just want to ensure that `ArrayList2` is NOT empty.

Comment: @jfpoilpret: u r right my arraylist2 is empty so i have checked ma query n i got the combo box filled.thank u so so so so much.thanks a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(yourstringarray);
                    item_combobox.setModel( model );
```

n ma problem get solved....

Answer (score 2):

you have to implements [ComboBoxModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387299/after-adding-items-dynamically-to-jcombobox-in-swing-those-values-are-not-appear/7388965#7388965) and add/remove/change `Items` in the `Model`, not in the `JComboBox`, nor somewhere in the `Array`, `List` or `Vector`, sure is possible but you have to execute your code on EDT and always replace `Array`, `List` or `Vector` for concreted `JComboBox`, don't do it that this way :-)

maybe you have problem with [Concurency in the Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), maybe changes are done, but outside EDT, more about your issues [pass events wrapped into invokeLater()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216937/multiple-jcombobox/7217204#7217204) and [multiple-jcombobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246005/jcombobox-change-another-jcombobox/6246655#6246655)

Comment: +1 for suggestion of using a model. However I don't think this would solve the problem.

Comment: changes are done INSIDE the EDT because the code is executed from an `ItemListener`; hence there's no specific threading problem in that example (except the fact that DB access would better be performed with `SwingWorker` but that's not the source of the problem).

Answer (score 0):

You must read:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

It will help you to deal with java comboboxes.

Seems you should use an ActionListener as event to populate second combobox.

For your debug problems you should check [bug 6714678](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6714678) from java bugtracker

```
-Dsun.awt.disablegrab=true
```

should solve your debug problem (since 2008)

See could not work for old jdks as on 2007 related [bug 6517045](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6517045) says:

> after discussion we came to conclusion that this (debug on combobox events) is just one more place when it is not
>   wise to stop in debugger (the same is true for DnD, fullscreen).